# Как заставить IE игнорировать участок кода JS?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

Есть код:

```
  const links = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
  const sections = [... document.querySelectorAll('.forJS')];
  const callback = (entries) => {
    links.forEach((link) => link.classList.remove('active'));
    const elem = entries.find((entry) => entry.isIntersecting);
    if (elem) {
      const index = sections.findIndex((section) => section === elem.target);
      links[index].classList.add('active');
    }
  }

  let observer = new IntersectionObserver(callback, {
    rootMargin: '0px',
    threshold: 0.5
  });

  sections.forEach((section) => observer.observe(section));
```

IE ругается на вторую строчку кода(`SCRIPT1002: Синтаксическая ошибка`), подcвечиваются квадратные скобки [], затем еще как какую то (если удалить ту на которую он ругался до этого) и т.д. Как можно заставить его игнорировать этот участок кода? Пытался делать так:

```
const isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false   || !!document.documentMode;//Определяем IE ли это
if(!isIE){//Если не IE выполняем участок кода

  ...Весь код...

};
```

Что можно сделать еще?

Comment: Переписать без spread или взять какой-либо транспилятор (babel, например) Чтобы он сделал это за вас

Comment: В случае синтаксических ошибок, у вас не получится обойти участки кода: IE просто не сможет спарсить код, чтобы обработать условия пропуска. Нужно или переписывать, или транспилировать.

Comment: С помощью php решил. Опишу в отдельном комменте, если интересно.

Comment: Почему бы не взять babel? Сейчас его вроде все используют

Comment: Я попробовал, браузер все равно ошибки выдает :SCRIPT5022: Исключение брошено и не поймано.

Comment: Вообще можно обернуть участок кода в `try {} catch () {}`

Comment: Мне кажется в любом случае он просканирует весь код и выдаст опять ошибку. А может быть через JS проверять IE ли это, если да, то закомментить скрипт, который не хотим выполнять. Вот только как закомментить нужный скрипт через JS?

Answer (score 0):

Где-то, когда-то нашел - выручает

```
    function browserCheck() {
      const ua = navigator.userAgent.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie)\/?\s*(\.?\d+(\.\d+)*)/i);
      let browser = '';
      if (navigator.userAgent.match(/Edge/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./i)) {
        browser = 'msie';
      } else {
        browser = ua[1].toLowerCase();
      }
      document.body.classList.add(browser);
      return browser;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если вы используете php, можно сделать так. Выносим этот код, на который IE ругается в отдельный файл. Затем следующий скрипт на php, который определяет, является ли текущий браузер IE и затем обычный условный оператор. Если у пользователя не IE загружаем скрипт, иначе нет.

```
$ie = htmlentities($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
<?php if (preg_match('~MSIE|Internet Explorer~i', $ie) || (strpos($ie, 'Trident/7.0') == false && strpos($ie, 'rv:11.0') == false)) {
?>
<script src="js/ourScript.js"></script>
<?php };?>
```

UPD. Можно и без php, но опять таки в отдельный файл наш скрипт и таким образом подключаем:

```
<!--[if !IE]-->
 <script src="js/ourScript.js"></script>
<!--[endif]-->
```

Comment: Потрясающий костыльный костыль!

Comment: И в чем же его проблема и какие альтернативы? Если есть элегантный вариант на чистом JS, с радостью буду использовать.

Comment: Вам же выше написали, что этот участок кода всего лишь надо переписать c версии ES2018 на версию ES5.